# Controller undefined when in same file as view

Tags: angularjs

I am able to render the view for userForm.html but I keep getting an error saying:

```
angular.js:12722 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'userFormController' is not a function, got undefined
```

The controller in question is userFormController just like the above error displays.

userFormController

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('userFormController',['$scope', function($scope){
        console.log('You are in the userFormController');
}]);
```

configuration.js

```
angular.module('myApp').
config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/',{
        templateUrl: "pages/mainPage/mainPage.html",
        controller:"mainPageController"
    })
        .when('/userForm',{
           templateUrl: 'pages/userForm/userForm.html',
           controller: 'userFormController'
        })
        .when('',{
            templateUrl:'',
            controller:''
        })
    .otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});

});
```

index.html

```
<body ng-app="myApp">

  <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
  <![endif]-->

  <div ng-view></div>

  <div>Angular seed app: v<span app-version></span></div>

  <!-- In production use:
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/x.x.x/angular.min.js"></script>
  -->
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="components/version/version.js"></script>
  <script src="components/version/version-directive.js"></script>
  <script src="components/version/interpolate-filter.js"></script>
  <script src="pages/mainPage/mainPageController.js"></script>
  <script src="configuration.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

mainPage.html

```
<div>

<h2>Hello World</h2>

    <button onclick="window.location.href= '#/userForm' ">Next Page</button>

</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where are your userFormController.js in script tags ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include your userFormController.js file in your index.html like this:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">

  <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
  <![endif]-->

  <div ng-view></div>

  <div>Angular seed app: v<span app-version></span></div>

  <!-- In production use:
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/x.x.x/angular.min.js"></script>
  -->
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="components/version/version.js"></script>
  <script src="components/version/version-directive.js"></script>
  <script src="components/version/interpolate-filter.js"></script>
  <script src="pages/mainPage/mainPageController.js"></script>
  <script src="pages/userForm/userFormController.js"></script>
  <script src="configuration.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```